# How to visualize Vector3 in three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d

I was reading the tutorial on how to draw lines in three.js documentation and the code used looked like this:

The code is fine and have no problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/threejs_tutorial/build_threejs.html"></script>
        <script>
        
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
        camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //create a blue LineBasicMaterial
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );

        const points = [];
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

        const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );


        scene.add( line );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But what caught my eye is the *const points = []*,  *points.push* and *Vector3* part of the code.

```
const points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );
```

I don't understand the function of *const points = [];* and why was it used.

I don't understand the function of *points.push* and why was it used.

The Three.Vector3 command looks like it position points in 3D plane. For this case it looks like this:

[image: functionofVector3]

How do we visualize the Vector3 in three.js and why is the output looked like this?

[image: OutputOfProgram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const points = [];` creates an empty [Array<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object, that is, an Array with no elements, which has `.length` of zero.

`points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );` adds the new `Vector3` to the end of the array.  Since the array starts with zero elements, the first call adds a first element; the second adds a second element; etc.

For why the geometry is displayed with line segments, compare [Line](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=line#api/en/objects/Line) with [Points](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=points#api/en/objects/Points).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, comrade! But why we need the array?

Comment: How else would you provide multiple Vector3s to the geometry?

Comment: Ooooh...I see....the purpose of the array is make the points created by Vector3 "real" because calling Vector3 alone merely states the position of point. Calling the array and putting Vector3 in the array creates a real, specified point because array is an object, so the point specified by the Vector3 in the array becomes an object too.

Comment: I wish the threejs.org website is no longer down because currently it is down on my place.

Comment: I have written an answer based on my understanding of your answer. Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh yes...this is actually the explanation of the purpose of these snippets of code.

The purpose of

> const points = [];

is make the points created by Vector3 "real" because calling Vector3 alone merely states the position of point. Calling the array and putting Vector3 in the array creates a real, specified point because array is an object, so the point specified by the Vector3 in the array becomes an object too.

The purpose of

> points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );

> points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );

and

> points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );

is to position the desired point using Vector3 within the viewing frustrum of the camera...

Comment: @Phil N. Is this the correct explanation for the 4 snippets of code,

Comment: It's not that a vector needs to be "made real."  A vector is just a location, just a very specific way of saying "over there."  "Over there" doesn't tell us anything about that location -- what's there, or whether it's hot or cold, or if anybody owns it, or anything.  Similarly, it's troublesome to think about "visualizing" a vector, because a vector has no intrinsic visual properties.  What we have to do is to *represent* a vector or vector(s) by telling the machine to draw points, or line segments, or triangles "over there" ...

Comment: ... So the only importance of the array in this regard is that the machine either allows (Points, Lines) or requires (Mesh) more than one vector to be represented by a single object, and that "more than one"-ness is a facility that the array provides.  The vector, in this regard, is only a location at which we place something that *does* have intrinsic visual properties.